# Controller_trySomething Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].<Constructor>() at line 14 column 31

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am getting this error on my page:

> Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].() at line 14 column 31

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class Controller_trySomething {
    public ApexPages.StandardController myAccountController {get; set;}
    public Account Account {get; set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController myUserController {get; set;}
    public User User {get; set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController standardContactController;
    public Controller_trySomething(ApexPages.StandardController cntrl) {
     standardContactController = cntrl;

        Contact con = (Contact)cntrl.getRecord();
        list<Account> cc =[select Id,Name from Account where Id=:con.AccountId];
        list<User> cd =[select Id,FirstName from User where id=:con.OwnerId];

        myAccountController = new ApexPages.StandardController();
        myUserController = new ApexPages.StandardController();
       }
        public pageReference doSaveAll() {
        standardContactController.save();
        myAccountController.save();
        myUserController.save();
        return null;
    //}
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Controller_trySomething" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
<apex:form >
       <apex:outputText rendered="false" value="{!Contact.AccountId}{!Contact.OwnerId}"/>
        My Contact's First Name is: <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        My Contact's Account Name is <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        My Contact's Owner First Name is: <apex:inputField value="{!User.FirstName}"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Save Contact" action="{!cancel}"/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Save Account" action="{!myAccountController.save}"/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Save User" action="{!myUserController.save}"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Save All" action="{!doSaveAll}"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Cancel to Contact" action="{!cancel}"/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Cancel to Account" action="{!myAccountController.cancel}"/>
        <apex:CommandButton value="Cancel to User" action="{!myUserController.cancel}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate a `ApexPages.StandardController` with an `SObject` record. In this case, I think you want:

```
myAccountController = new ApexPages.StandardController(cc[0]);
myUserController = new ApexPages.StandardController(cd[0]);
```

Also, I highly recommend more descriptive naming. I have no idea what you mean by `cc` or `cd`, even given the context above.

Comment: @farook   -  Did it solve issue ?
#Adrian  I tried replicating the same but getting error 
Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].<Constructor>(Id)
 for both these values.

Comment: Yes I solved That One But its Not Work Properly Account Created Contact Created But User Not Created For Contact